# How to import/trim on R a certain amount of columns and rows from a large .txt file containing matrix data?

Tags: r, matrix, text-files, edit, large-files

This is my first question, so be gentle...
So, I have a matrix with 35000 rows and 35000 columns, that looks like this:-

```
L7U3V2_MYXSD/48-1100         0.000000 0.645594 0.665709 0.560038 0.542502 0.529075 0.638380 0.513929 0.574427 0.595806 0.588179 0.598095 0.592168 0.723671 0.603083 0.602502 0.710938 0.616201 0.714976 0.734634 0.595192 0.611641 0.690661 0.607315 0.728240 0.595765 0.602885 0.713729 0.609827 0.708775 0.604629 0.610636 0.686829 0.614423 0.705882 0.592878 0.604046 0.714008 0.610790 0.708213 ....

L7U3V2_MYXSD/1130-2180 0.617956 0.712107 0.652845 0.721747 0.642925 0.691049 0.655801 0.726133 0.672498 0.686217 0.673550 0.570741 0.631985 0.724172 0.700855 0.696239 0.718173 0.708691 0.655205 0.613485 0.601140 0.600382 0.613485 0.556304 0.751451 0.704981 0.714425 0.711930 0.692456 0.750242 0.664745 0.645130 0.726027 0.751210 0.730845 0.722543 0.674441 0.690500 0.675516 0.606838 ....

.

.

.

.
```

Because of Excel's limit in the number of columns I can't edit or just copy the ones I want, and also the poor RAM on my computer (it weighs 13gb).

I want to trim the matrix to 5000 columns and 5000 rows, I've been trying with R but subsetting isn't working, and I don't know MatLAB enough to try.

Does anyone know how I might be able to do this using command line or whatever??

Comment: You can specify the rows and columns that you want to keep/remove. Try `s = dat[1:5000,1:5000]` where `dat` is the dataset and `s` is the name of the trimmed dataset.

Comment: for that I have to load it as a dataset, and the weigth of the file doesn't let me do it... i meant like, triming it from the command line so my computer can do it. Like triming the first 1000 characters of every line on the txt file or something

Comment: Do you want the first 5000 rows and columns? Linux command line tools can do this - for example to get the first 3 lines and first 3 fields: - `head -3 test.csv | cut -f 1-3 -d, > short.csv` (note `-d,` is for comma-separated)

Comment: Agreed with Spacedman. If you can't load it in memory, you can't load it in R. You should be looking for a command line solution, not an R solution.

Comment: ... and for a command line solution tag with your operating system and maybe `sed` or `awk` if they're available on your OS, don't bother with the `r` tag.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear. Lack of OS information prevents specific replies.

Answer (score 2):

Like Gregor commented, if you can't load it into memory, you won't be able to work with it in R. It is possible to load smaller subsets of the file though. Perhaps you could set up a loop to analyze the data in smaller batches. That's a topic for another question though.

I used the following code to create a test file:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

# create a large data.table with random values. Appending this 5k x 35k
# together into the same file should replicate the 35k x 35k matrix
very_large_mtrx <- matrix(rexp(5000*35000), nrow = 5000, ncol = 35000) %>%
  data.table()

for (i in 1:7) {
  fwrite(x = very_large_mtrx,
         file = "test_matrix.txt",
         append = TRUE,
         sep = " ",
         showProgress = TRUE)
}
```

This creates a ~18gb File which is indeed larger than the majority of pcs can handle in memory. To get a subset of the data contained in the file, I'd recommend using data.table's `fread` function. It's one of the fastest and memory efficient file readers. [This Link](https://notesbytim.wordpress.com/2014/03/31/fread-vs-read-table/) has some more information about possible memory efficient solutions. The following code takes about 4 minutes to load the 5,000x5000 row subset that you requested. Memory use increased ~5gb during this process.

To answer your title question: How to import a certain number of columns and rows, specify the `nrows`(rows) and `select`(columns) arguments of `fread`. The `skip` argument can also be used to specify the starting row to get data if you don't want to start from the first row.

```
tst_input <- fread(input = "./test_matrix.txt",
                   header = FALSE,
                   sep = " ",
                   nrows = 5000,
                   select = 1:5000,
                   data.table = TRUE)
```

Check out `?scan` for another solution which allows you to explicitly define the number of rows and columns to read into memory.

Comment: Or you can `open()` a channel to the file and read a line at a time with `readLines`, keep what you want, leave what you don't.